# Rendering a collection isn't rendering all items in the collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems very elementary, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a @videos collection (which debugging @videos.count reveals to be 4), but the line `<%= render @videos %>` is only rendering 2 of the 4 items. Here is the controller method (VideosController):

```
  def index
    @video = Video.new(athlete_id: current_user.id, sport_id: current_athlete_sport.id)
    @videos = current_user.videos_for_sport(current_athlete_sport).order("date DESC")
    debugger
    respond_with @videos
  end
```

And the _video partial that the aforementioned `<%= render @videos %>` line is rendering:

```
<%= form_for video do |f| %>
  <div class="row edit-video-container <%= video == @videos.pop ? 'last' : '' %>">
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 video-thumbnail">
          <%= image_tag video.thumbnail_url || asset_path("video-encoding-placeholder.png"), {alt: "", title: "#{video.name || "My video" + video.id}"} %>
          <div class="video-ribbon">
            <ul>
              <li class="pull-left">
                <%= link_to "#video-player-modal", { data: { toggle: "modal", link: video.mp4_video_url, thumbnail: video.thumbnail_url }, role: "button", class: "video-player-link" } do %>
                  <i class="icon video-play"></i>
                  <p>Play</br>Video</p>
                <% end %>
              </li>
              <li class="pull-left">
                <%= link_to rotate_video_path(video, direction: "ccw"), :data => { :method => "put", :confirm => "Are you sure?", :type => 'json' } do %>
                  <i class="icon video-rotate-left"></i>
                  <p>Rotate</br>Left</p>
                <% end %>
              </li>
              <li class="pull-left">
                <%= link_to rotate_video_path(video, direction: "cw"), :data => { :method => "put", :confirm => "Are you sure?", :type => 'json' } do %>
                  <i class="icon video-rotate-right"></i>
                  <p>Rotate</br>Right</p>
                <% end %>
              </li>
              <li class="pull-left">
                <%= link_to video_path(video), :data => { :method => "delete", :confirm => "Are you sure?", :type => 'json' } do %>
                  <i class="icon video-delete"></i>
                  <p>Delete</br>Video</p>
                <% end %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= f.check_box :featured, { checked: video.featured?, class: "autosave checkbox-right", data: { event: 'change' } } %>
          <%= label_tag "video-checkbox-featured-#{video.id}", "Use as featured video?", { class: "checkbox-right-label" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= label :video, :name, "Video Name" %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, { class: "span4 autosave"} %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= label :video, :video_type_id, "Video Type" %>
          <%= f.select:video_type_id, VideoType.all.collect { |vid| [vid.name, vid.id] }, { include_blank: "Choose One", selected: video.video_type_id }, { class: "chosen-select autosave", id: "", data: { event: 'change' } } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= label :video, :sport_id, "Video Sport" %>
          <%= f.select :sport_id, current_user.sports.collect { |sp| [sp.name, sp.id] }, { include_blank: "Choose one", selected: video.sport_id }, { class: "chosen-select autosave", id: "", data: { event: "change" } } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= label :video, :date, "Date Recorded" %>
          <%= f.text_field :date, {class: "autosave date datePicker span4", value: js_date(video.date) } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= label :video, :uniform_number, "Uniform Number" %>
          <%= f.text_field :uniform_number, { class: "autosave span4"} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Again, throwing a debugger in the controller, or a debug on the page just before the `<%= render @videos %>` line shows 4 videos, however only 2 are actually being rendered. At a bit of a loss here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
video == @videos.pop
```

Pop takes out a member from your collection. You shouldn't use it here because you brake the looping.

If this is the case, I suppose you can see only the first and the last item of your collection.